# Lodash Finding a key in an array

Tags: ecmascript-6, lodash

I have my array as below

```
"participant": {
        "13":"xyz",
"26": "abc",
"38": "nmy"}
```

I am trying to find the value with the key 13. I tried couple of ways but I am getting undefined.

_.find(participant, 13);

I tried writing a function also but I think ES6 or lodash can solve it easily.

Answer (score 2):

Your simple object doesn't require any kind of library, nor a function. All you need is

```
console.log(obj.participant[13]);
```

This will log the value, or undefined if the key doesn't exist.